# vb6 - readfile hang on read serial port?

Tags: vb6, readfile

i use readfile to read data from serial port by api instead of WinComm. it works okay but hang on data receive when other side does not sent data, here are some codes:

```
'----------on port connect section---------------
With cTimeOuts
   .ReadIntervalTimeout = 20
   .ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 20
   .ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 20
   .WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 20
   .WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 20
End With
rtLng = SetCommTimeouts(hPort, cTimeOuts)

'----------on data receive section---------------
With dOverlapped
   .Internal = 0
   .InternalHigh = 0
   .offset = 0
   .OffsetHigh = 0
   .hEvent = 0
End With

call ReadFile(hPort, BytesBuffer(0), UBound(BytesBuffer) + 1, dwBytesRead, dOverlapped)
```

i tried:

a. set `ReadIntervalTimeout` to `MAXDWORD` and `ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier` & `ReadTotalTimeoutConstant` both to `0`, it can avoid hang on receive data, but the receive data will incomplete for random occurred, so this is not my option.

b. some example code on internet using
`Call ReadFile(hPort, BytesBuffer(0), UBound(BytesBuffer) + 1, dwBytesRead, 0)` using `0` instead of `Overlapped` setting, but the program crashed.

so i don't know using what to fix this, `another thread`? or `Overlapped`? some actual vb6 code is better cause i'm not familiar with this section, thank you!

Comment: Here is a [serial port connector class](https://github.com/Unicontsoft/UcsFiscalPrinters/blob/master/src/Connectors/cSerialPortConnector.cls) using overlapped I/O that is battle tested to not hang/crash with all sorts of USB-to-Serial converters too.

Comment: @wqw i will try the code, thank you.